# How to update part of a string column in a table, using PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have to update/replace a part of the string in one of the column in table which is having 137 records.

Requirement: 
Before update, column is having value like:

```
home/user/tarun/attachments/a.jpg
```

After update, column values should be like :

```
home/common/attachments/a.jpg
```

So, a part of the string should of updated. How can I write the PL/SQL script for it?

Comment: update [TableName] set [ColumnName] = 'home/common/attachments/a.jpg' where [ID] = 'yourId'

Comment: right ....but you are giving update for one record ... there are different values after attachments/ n each record ... so please help to write a script which can update 137 records in one go .

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? Why can't you simply run an `update` statement.

Comment: I would need to write a update for 127 records not for only onle ....it would be tedious

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with SQL. Why you would need PLSQL for this?

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME>
SET <COLUMN_NAME> = REPLACE(<COLUMN_NAME>,'/user/tarun/','/common/');
```

Comment: You are welcome!! If this helped you plz accept the answer so it could be helpful to others too.